# UITextField alpha for text only

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I set colors of the UITextField:

```
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
textField.alpha = 0.5f;
```

Alpha channel is set for bouth bkg and text colors.
How to set alpha separately for text color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
textField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
```

try set textColor alpha.